Unable to ssh to ubiquiti cloud gateway ultra
I have ssh enabled in the cloug gateways settings and set an ssh password. I'm using putty.
It will not accept my credentials. I had tried root and the ssh pw. I have tried admin and that password. I have tried root and the admin pw, and admin and the ssh pw. I don't know what else it could possibly be. I'm trying to ssh into it so I can run the adoption command.

If it's not adopted yet (or if you reset it to factory defaults), the SSH username is ubnt and the password is also ubnt.
If it has been previously adopted (and not reset), the username and password are in advanced settings in the Unifi portal.
